# Copy data from Sharepoint to Blob in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory, I need to copy data from an Excel file that is stored in our company sharepoint. I have read some documentation on this, however, it seems more complicated than it should - considering Azure Data Factory and Sharepoint are owned by the same corporation.

I know this might be a vague and subjective question but hopefully someone can be helpful:

How can one most easily copy data from a Sharepoint to a blob storage in Data Factory?

Let me know if this was too vague or if you need more information - then I will try to elaborate.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Azure data factory is still a evolving offering and even though all the components belong to MSFT itself, sharepoint connector is currently not supported in ADF.
You can upvote for that request in Azure feedback site.

So as a temporary workaround, you can leverage the sharepoint online REST API via HHTP connector as source and destination as blob storage in copy activity.
To connect to sharepoint via HTTP connector, you would need an app registration.

Below link would provide advanced details for the same:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sharepoint-online-list